# Project wide import of library Python

Tags: python

I'm building a PyCharm Plugin which adds several capabilities such as support of a custom language.

The user writes Python code in multiple files and needs to use some stubs as a part of the development.

My current solution is adding module `x` to the project, the module has the stubs and then the users need to add `from x import mystubs` in the beginning of each file. Then, when they want to write something with them they use `mystubs.stub(input)`.

Is there a way to globally import (perhaps in the project settings) the stubs module?
The end goal is that the users would be able to write `mystubs.stub(input)` without any errors, and without them having to add `from x import mystubs` at the beginning of each file.

Thank you,
Shachar